# Reading all files within a directory Java ( assingning priroities to files )

Tags: java, file, nio

I am trying to read all files within a directory using java nio, i have the following directory structure

```
--dir1
  |
  -file1
  -file2
  -file3
```

Now i need to make sure that file3 gets read first and then followed by file2 and then file1, i.e i need to assign some priorities to the files and then read higher priority files first rather than the lower priority ones, how can i achieve this ?

Comment: How do you assign priorities? Your example is just sorting files, file3 -> file2-> file1... Or do you have any file that contains priorities

Comment: in this case sorting will work, i need to assign priorities based on the name of the file like filenamea, filenameb, filenamec, each of these files will be of a different type

Comment: I am agree with @AbdullahTellioglu if you want to access files by priorities you must have a file which having file names and priorities associated with it.

Comment: @VikasSuryawanshi i agree, my question is how to assign these priorities

Comment: Funny how you use "I" throughout most of your question and at the end you say, "how can we achieve this"

Comment: @MichaelMarkidis edited :P

Comment: What are the criteria for the priorities? Is it something static? If static you might either create an additional file to specify the read order and read the files in that specific order or create a class implementing the [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) interface to sort the file list by your needs. If dynamic you should explain the rules here. What are the different file types? How does the file type impact the read priority?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `PriorityQueue` as i have implimented that in simple way hope this solves your problem

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Comparator<String> comparator = new StringLengthComparator();
        PriorityQueue<String> queue = 
            new PriorityQueue<String>(10, comparator);
        queue.add("file3");
        queue.add("file1");
        queue.add("file2");
        while (queue.size() != 0)
        {
            System.out.println(queue.remove());
        }
    }
}
```

Hear i am comparing your condition using comparator

```
import java.util.Comparator;

    public class StringLengthComparator implements Comparator<String> {
        @Override
        public int compare(String x, String y) {
            if (x.equalsIgnoreCase("file3")) {
                return -1;
            }
            if (x.equalsIgnoreCase("file1")) {
                return 1;
            }
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

Assign your priorities as you like and read it .

Resulting

```
file3
file2
file1
```

Comment: how will u use contains instead of equalsIgnoreCase

Comment: let's say if the file name contains a specific substring then it should be at the head of the queue

Comment: parse the string,

Comment: i used contains function,
like if(a.contains()&&b.contains())return 0 else if(a.contains()&&!b.contains()) return 1 so on

Comment: Pattern.compile(x).matcher("123123file3sdfsdf").find() this works still perfect

Comment: Sorry i didn't get this